# SQL query to get latest data of each year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

PAPF

```
PERSON_ID               NAME
19                      XYZ
8                       ABC
10                      YGDF
1                       SMITH
```

PEEVF

```
EFFECTIVE_START_DATE        EFFECTIVE_END_DATE              PERSON_ID           ELEMENT_NAME            VALUE

01-JAN-2021                     10-JAN-2021                     19                  Bonus                   9.1         
11-JAN-2021                     28-MAR-2021                     19                  Bonus                   11
29-MAR-2021                     10-APR-2021                     19                  Bonus                   11.1
11-APR-2021                     31-DEC-2021                     19                  Bonus                   10
11-APR-2022                     30-APR-2022                     19                  Bonus                   12
19-APR-2022                     30-MAY-2022                     19                  LTP                     09

01-JAN-2019                     30-APR-2019                     8                   Bonus                   5
11-MAR-2021                     10-JAN-2021                     10                  Bonus                   11
11-JAN-2021                     28-MAR-2021                     10                  Bonus                   11.1


20-JAN-2019                     08-MAR-2019                     1                   LTP                     9
11-APR-2019                     19-AUG-2019                     1                   LTP                     9.8
```

I want to create a query such that I get the latest Bonus and LTP for an employee in each particular year.

The current query is as follows -

```
select name, element_name, value 
from per_all_people_f papf ,
per_element_f PEEVF
where peevf.person_id = papf.person_id
and sysdate between papf.effective_start_Date and papf.effective_end_Date
```

the output should look like -

```
PERSON_ID           CURRENT_YEAR_BONUS          CURRENT_YEAR_LTP        FY2019_LTP      FY2021_LTP      FY2020_LTP     FY2021_BONUS         FY2020_BONUS        FY2019_BONUS 
19                        12                            09                                                                  10
8                                                                                                                                                               5   
10                                                                                                                          11.1
1                                                                           9.8
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged